# Slashes and hashes in Perl and metacharacters

Tags: regex, perl

I'd asked earlier about escaping special characters and understand the rules around // and ## yet the example below doesn't work and by my understanding I need to escape, the escape character. It's being searched for as match for it's usual meaning of \ between the names. I'm stumped. Please help. This has me in knots, despite probably appearing easy to the masses.I know I could have written it as $userInfo =~ #\#;

```
#!C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe

#strict
#diagnostics


$userInfo = "firstname\middlename\lastname.";


if($userInfo =~ m/\\/){ 
print("Found it");
}

else{
print("No match found");
}
```

Comment: **NEVER** use backslashes to separate data items!! Use proper slashes, or colons, or whitespace, or anything but a backslash!  Plus if you hadn’t disabled warnings, it would have epxlained what yhou did wrong.  Always use warnings. Always use strict.  And never use a backslash!

Comment: I did that for the specific purpose of the match exercise only. It's not something I'd do routinely but thank you. Any help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The problem there is that you have to escape the backslash in your `$userInfo` assignment too:

```
$userInfo = "firstname\\middlename\\lastname.";
```

Comment: Yes, many thanks - tried it (and the advice below). Both work and thanks for the heads up. Much appreciated. I'm just finding it hard remembering.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to search a string which contains the literal bakslash character `\`.  Double quotes interpolate.  Use single quotes instead.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $userInfo = 'firstname\middlename\lastname.';

if ($userInfo =~ m/\\/){
    print("Found it");
}
else{
    print("No match found");
}
```

The warnings pragma would have generated a warning message.

See also: [Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with toolic, if you can, use single quotes.
It will save some preprocessing time needed for string interpolation.

However, if you really need to escape special characters, you can write it like this:

```
  #!C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe

  #strict
  #diagnostics

  $userInfo = "firstname\\middlename\\lastname.";      #please note escaped backslahes
  if($userInfo =~ m/\\/)
  { 
    print("Found it");
  }
  else
  {
    print("No match found");
  }
```